Proving algorithms' correctness
I am working in a computational subfield of mathematics, so there are algorithms whose correctness I have to prove. Usually, algorithms are formulated in an imperative manner, i.e., as a sequence of instructions, including (re)assignments of values to variables. This is different from mathematical writing, and I noticed that every time I reason over an algorithm, my arguments are less strict than when reasoning about a (conventional) mathematical statement. I think I need some strategies how to prove algorithms in general. Ways that I know of:

induction: If the algorithm contains a 'main loop', I can index all variables that may change by the index of the iteration, and do induction on that. Closely related:
invariants: I can prove that every iteration preserves some kind of property, and/or establishes a new one.
recursion: recursive algorithms probably lend them selves readily to mathematical treatment.

The induction way might get quite clumsy if I really write out the indices of the iteration. How should I resolve this? And what other strategies are there?

It might be easier to help you if you post some algorithm you are having difficulty reasoning with. Just like proofs in math can take several different forms, so is proving algorithmic correcteness. Do provide an example, with you going through the analysis and mentioning the places where you are facing issues.
